# Nginx location testing is not redirecting to the correct page

Tags: nginx

I am completely new to nginx, therefore please be kind. I have my domain registered and I am trying to get the following to happen.

When a user enters example.com I want them to get a 404. When they enter in example.com/test I want them to get my index.html. This is an unusual use case, but its what I would like.

I have set-up a site under

/var/www/example/public_html // /with index.html as well 
/var/www/example/public_html/test //with index.html as well

The config is located under:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example

The symbolic link is working and is:
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example

Heres my config for example:

```
   server
{
        listen 80;
        server_name example;

        #not sure if i need the below to lines?
    root /var/www/example/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location /
        {
                return 404;
        }

        location /test/
        {
                root /var/www/example/public_html/test;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
}`
```

When I enter example.com, I do get my 404. But when I go to example.com/test I just get a 404 as well, when I was hoping the /test/ would be matching and change the root so the index would show.

If I get rid of the two location checks, then typing www.example.com goes to my index.html page as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to start removing the final slash after "test" in the second location predicate: `location /test {`. The URL www.example.com/test is not the same as www.example.com/test/.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I made that change. Did a service restart and it had no effect. I also did "~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful"

Comment: Additionally, the permissions on that folder are below, and look OK:
/var/www/example/public_html/test/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 dev dev 4096 Aug  5 17:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 dev dev 4096 Aug  5 17:40 ..
dev@:~$ Also put two locations in for the different permutations and I still get the 404

Comment: Check error.log and you'll see what you did wrong. Also read docs.

Comment: Dear Alexey, I check the log and found: 2015/08/06 10:19:46 [error] 8402#0: *3 "/var/www/example/public_html/test/test/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: ***, server: example, request: "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
So I changed my config to:

server 
{
        listen 80;
 server_name example;
        root /var/www/example/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location /
        {
                return 404;
        }

        location /test
        {
  index index.html index.htm;
 }
} And it now works.

Comment: So when you are modifying the root matching in the second location, it looks like it concatenates the context of the get URI onto to it as well. Which explains the test\test. @Alex Mazzariol - the current location works for both "/test" and "/test/". Thanks again for your help.